Why isn't the instantaneous rate of sender considered during the congestion control of TCP?
The strategy of traditional congestion control(CC) to avoid congestion is to control the window size of the sender within one RTT. However, if the sender's instantaneous rate is very high and the bottleneck link has a very small bandwith, even a relatively small window size still might lead to queuing at the router before the bottleneck link. So instead of adjusting the window size of sender, wouldn't it be more effictive to adjust the sender's rate to stop the congestion?
Almost no course mentions this problem. When calculating the speed of senders, window size/RTT which is the average speed is often be used. But isn't the sender rate actually determined by the sender's proccessing rate of datagrams and the banwidth of its ethernet interface? This is my sencond question.

TL;DR: don't look at a single feature of congestion control in isolation but instead observe how they work together.

... if the sender's instantaneous rate is very high

It should not be very high. That's why there is a slow start in TCP.

... might lead to queuing at the router before the bottleneck link.

Routers are not supposed to extensively queue packets but instead to drop packets quickly if they cannot be delivered. This helps in quickly adjusting the window size - which gets increased on successful delivery (i.e. ACK received in TCP) and decreased on packet loss.
See Bufferbloat for more on what happens if routers wrongly extensively queue packets instead of dropping these quickly.
In addition to dropping packets there can also be Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN), which does not drop packets but instead delivers the packet but reflects back to the sender that congestion got experienced on the link. Thus the sender can adjust its behavior earlier compared to waiting for a dropped packet.

So instead of adjusting the window size of sender, wouldn't it be more effictive to adjust the sender's rate to stop the congestion?

The window size effectively reflects how fast the sender can send, since it can only have a limited amount of data "in flight" before it needs an acknowledgment. Even with ECN the senders speed is adjusted by tuning the window size.

But isn't the sender rate actually determined by the sender's proccessing rate of datagrams and the banwidth of its ethernet interface?

The senders rate is not only limited by how fast the sender itself could send (processing power and bandwidth of interface). But instead the properties of all the links between sender and receiver and the properties of the receiver itself needs to be included in the calculation: a slow link in between will cause a decrease of the senders rate as does a slow processing of data in the TCP/IP stack of some underpowered peer (like a tiny IoT device).

Consider people running a certain distance. The window size is analogous to the distance, but people can choose one of two ways to run:
1.Run at a very slow pace and never take a rest during the entire process.
2.Run at a relatively fast pace and take a rest before reaching the end.
Both methods can take the same time to cover the same distance but have different impacts on the runner. Simply controlling the distance (window size) might not effectively reduce the speed of the runner (sender rate)  which will lead to congestion. Speed control might be a more direct way to avoid congestion.

I don't know whether my analogy is correct.

@Nainoahs: I don't think your analogy is correct. To give you a more appropriate: The sender (start point) can not control how fast people run, i.e. how long packets need from sender to recipient. It has also no control about the quality of the track, i.e. if there are some bottlenecks, steep hills, ... It can only control how many people are on the track at the same time (window size) by letting others only start if it gets the information that enough of the previous ones arrived at the destination (recipient) and maybe (with ECN) if the track was crowded (congested) or not (binary info).

Thank you very very much for your example. I've got it and I misunderstood the working process and the meaning of the window size before.


adjust the sender's rate to stop the congestion?

That's what explicit congestion notification, defined in RFC 3168 is for.

ECN does not directly adjust the "sender's rate", i.e. how fast packets get delivered. It instead adjusts the window size, i.e. same mechanism like a detected packet loss. The main difference is that congestion gets detected earlier with ECN compared to packet loss and thus the window size can be tuned earlier, ideally avoiding packet loss completely this way.
